# Django -Website very slow on the first request

Tags: django, apache

I've a Django website deployed on Apache with Passenger that is very slow on the first request. The site becomes fast after the first request, but if no one visit the site for 2 or 3 hours the first request after this time of no activity in the site is again very slow.

Any clues on why this is happening?

Best Regards,

Comment: Maybe because at the first request django checks many url.py files, and those files contain many python packages imports (your views.py, etc...). And maybe those python modules are imported in the server memory at runtime instead of at server launching ?

Comment: that normal , certaintly that the website using a cache memory for the access available for 2 or 3 hours only